# Detect facebook share success

Tags: javascript, facebook, share

I am trying to detect if the user share my post on my website, and if it success or not. I've tried doing the following example from this reference. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

But I am getting an error on the dialog itself. The error I am getting is:

```
An error occurred. Please try again later.
```

I am testing this on localhost server.

Comment: Can you share some code what have you tried? Are you providing the correct `AppId` / `AccessToken` ?

Comment: Add `show_error: true` to your dialog parameters to get a little more info about what went wrong.